# Adding a column with function values to Spark dataframes with SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, data-science, sparkr

I am using SparkR to work with some project that includes R and spark in its technology stack.

I have to create new columns with booleans values returned from validation functions. I can do this job easily with spark dataframes and one expression like:

```
sdf1$result <- sdf1$value == sdf2$value
```

The problem is when I have to compare two dataframes of different lengths.

What is the best way to operate `sdf1` and `sdf2` dataframes with a function and assign the value to a new column of `sdf1`? Let's suppose that I want to generate a column with the minimum length between `sdf1` and `sdf2`.

Comment: Logically operation like `sdf1$result <- sdf1$value == sdf2$value` is invalid for the vectors with different lengths. Could you please give examples, what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have dataframes of different lengths, I logically assume that you have some column(s) that determines how to line up the values between the two dataframes. You will have to perform a join between the two dataframes on these columns (see SparkR::merge / SparkR::join) and then do your comparison operation to create your new column on the resulting dataframe.